# Alternative for CTE using LOCF prev expression in TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Subquery expression in [LOCF](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/gapfilling-interpolation/locf/) prev argument seems to re-run for me for each row, I can easily solve that problem by moving the subquery to the CTE, but in my specific case I can't use CTE because the query is intended to be composable/nested deep using interpolation and moving the CTE to every invokation is not feasible - what would be the alternative which do not involve using CTE (and is valid in TimescaleDB)?

This query is simplified but should show the issue clearly - the issue seems to be postgres not re-using the subqueries.

This is slow

```sql
SELECT 
  time_bucket_gapfill('3600', blocks.bl_timestamp) AS tick,
  locf(MAX(klines.high), (
    SELECT k2.high 
    FROM klines k2
    LEFT JOIN blocks b2 ON b2.bl_number = k2.block
    WHERE b2.bl_timestamp <= to_timestamp(1600000000)
    ORDER BY b2.bl_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )) AS high,
  locf(MIN(klines.low), (
    SELECT k2.low
    FROM klines k2
    LEFT JOIN blocks b2 ON b2.bl_number = k2.block
    WHERE b2.bl_timestamp <= to_timestamp(1600000000)
    ORDER BY b2.bl_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )) AS low
FROM klines
LEFT JOIN blocks ON blocks.bl_number = klines.block
WHERE blocks.bl_timestamp BETWEEN to_timestamp(1600000000) AND to_timestamp(1660000000)
GROUP BY tick
```

This works well but uses CTE

```sql
WITH last AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM klines k2
  LEFT JOIN blocks b2 ON b2.bl_number = k2.block
  WHERE b2.bl_timestamp <= to_timestamp(1600000000)
  ORDER BY b2.bl_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT 
  time_bucket_gapfill('3600', blocks.bl_timestamp) AS tick,
  locf(MAX(klines.high), (SELECT high FROM last)) AS high,
  locf(MIN(klines.low), (SELECT low FROM last)) AS low
FROM klines
LEFT JOIN blocks ON blocks.bl_number = klines.block
WHERE blocks.bl_timestamp BETWEEN to_timestamp(1600000000) AND to_timestamp(1660000000)
GROUP BY tick
```

The query in CTE is 1:1 to the subqueries and has **ONLY** static/hard-coded values such as timestamp (1600000000) - I was expecting postgres to re-use the subqueries since all the values are static but this is not the case for me. Ideally the solution would not involve creating functions.

I have solved the problem using CTE but it is not viable in my case, also tried joining the subquery 1 = 1 but it didn't work well because of grouping inside locf.

PSQL14, TSDB 2.8

Comment: Hmmm...this definitely shouldn't be happening, it should only run once per gapfill group. And we tested it internally and that didn't happen, I'm wondering if there's something going on with the to_timestamp call, but it could also be the join, can you give some more info about your schema and tables that you're using here?

Comment: @davidk I've uploaded the schema and non-simplified full query [here](https://imgur.com/a/S0jEO0d). I should mention the FROM table is realtime aggregate too.

Comment: @davidk also I can't confirm if it runs for each row or group but if it runs every group then it still will be slower than CTE, I'm getting 1second run time versus 6 seconds run time using subqueries.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what the join is doing or why it's necessary? Especially if klines is a continuous aggregate? Can you share the definition of the cagg and also explain what you're trying to accomplish with the query? The joining here is odd, especially when the where clause is on the joined table and I'm guessing that might be throwing things off, so perhaps we can try to figure out what we're trying to accomplish and simplify the join.

Explain analyze output for both ways of executing would also be helpful in identifying if this is an issue.

Comment: @davidk cagg works on block number, not timestamp because its made of events which happen at blocks and events do not contain timestamp - blocks do, so I need to join blocks to get the timestamps. Joining would not be needed if I could join inside cagg (or by denormalization to events) but I think joining inside cagg is tsdb limitation. This is weird design but I use bigints - not timestamps for my hypertables, because events do not have timestamps and I do not have nor I intend to store all blocks. [Here is cagg and plans](https://gist.github.com/jkbz64/083528b2753e903293f254cce586669b)

Comment: I guess perfect solution in my case would be to somehow trick postgres into optimizing the subqueries to CTE if that is even possible to avoid lifting up the CTE to every place the query is used - I'm kind of new to databases.

Comment: Okay, problem number 1 is that you're comparing timestamps and timestamptzs and they don't match, so we can't do any constraint exclusion on it as far as I can tell. That's no good...I'd cast your to_timestamp call to a timestamp (it actually returns timestamptz) or you could use timestamptzs rather than timestamps...which would be even better. 

Aside from that, I'd recommend turning JIT off, it sometimes causes slowdowns with us. 
Finally, i think the main gain you're getting from the CTE is that you run that query once instead of twice.

Comment: The once instead of twice problem is just because it appears twice in the statement, I think that's a PG issue rather than a Timescale one. 

With that said, i think all of this would be faster if you could do everything with blocks, which is what your hypertable is partitioned on. So I'd recommend getting the block number that corresponds to the time you're looking for (assuming blocks  are time ordered) and then write the where clause on block number. It will be much more efficient than the join you have.

Comment: @davidk Thank you very much for all the tips and your time. It's actually kind of amazing but just turning off jit made the query 5 times faster! (CTE 1800ms -> 300ms cold, subqueries 5000ms->1000ms cold) WOW, did not actually expect speedup like that! I'm going to explore the timestamp comparison issue but I don't think I will be able to operate on only blocks because I'm creating klines from out of different chains so all of them have their own block numbers and some generate faster some slower so timestamp is wildly different (I guess possible but not really worth atm). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oy. I wish that weren't as much of a problem. But I'm glad that helped!